# Get all disconnected pairs of nodes in a network

Tags: python, social-networking, igraph

I have coded a network using `igraph` (undirected), and I want to obtain the list of pairs of nodes that are not connected in the network.

Looking through the `igraph`'s documentation (Python), I haven't found a method that does this. Do I have to do this manually?

An related question: given any pair of nodes in the network, how do I find the list of common neighbors of these two nodes using `igraph`? Again, there seems no such method readily available in `igraph`.

Comment: Find the _connected components_ then the disconnected pairs can be produced by simply looping over every node and listing the nodes belonging to the components that that node is not a member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the first question (listing pairs of disconnected nodes): yes, you have to do this manually, but it is fairly easy:

```
from itertools import product

all_nodes = set(range(g.vcount())
disconnected_pairs = [list(product(cluster, all_nodes.difference(cluster))) \
                      for cluster in g.clusters()]
```

But beware, this could be a fairly large list if your graph is large and consists of a lot of disconnected components.

Re the second question (listing common neighbors): again, you have to do this manually but it only takes a single set intersection operation in Python:

```
set(g.neighbors(v1)).intersection(set(g.neighbors(v2)))
```

If you find that you need to do this for many pairs of nodes, you should probably create the neighbor sets first:

```
neighbor_sets = [set(neis) for neis in g.get_adjlist()]
```

Then you can simply write `neighbor_sets[i]` instead of `set(g.neighbors(i))`.